# REXX: writing long string to pds member

Tags: zos, rexx

i'm writing a rexx script on a z/OS (ADCD version) at my university.
I want to write a very long string to a pds member with diskw.
Sadly rexx doesn't automaticly break the line so only about half the string is written to the member. My string is a command that i am concatenating, executing and that i want to write to a log.

```
/*REXX*/
"ALLOCATE DATASET('"FILEPATH"') FILE(FILE) SHR REUSE"
command = "adduser" username
command = command || " TSO(ACCTNUM(ACCT) PROC(DBSPROC)",
"MAXSIZE(6072) SIZE(5000) MSGCLASS(H) UNIT(SYSALLDA))"
LOG.1 = command
LOG.2 = "Other Stuff"
"EXECIO" 2 "DISKW FILE (STEM LOG." 
"EXECIO 0 DISKW FILE (FINIS"
"FREE FILE(FILE)"
```

The Log created now only contains my command to a certain character and the rest of my command is not written to the member. like this:

```
adduser john TSO(ACCTNUM(ACCT) PROC(DBSPROC) MAXSIZE(6072) SIZE(5
```

Do you have any idea how to make rexx break the line and write my whole command?

Comment: You break it up in rexx. Rexx has functions like length,  substr and subword which you could use to break the command string up

Comment: okay. thanks i was hoping there was a more convenient way...

Answer (score 0):

1. Define the log file as recfm(v) lrecl(32100) block(32108) , or (vb) where the lrecl is the expected maximum record length.
2. Write to it as follows:

   push command

   "EXECIO  1 DISKW FILE"

   push "other stuff"

   "EXECIO  1 DISKW FILE"

Comment: That results in the same truncation as my first aproach. But thanks for the idea

Answer (score 0):

The ALLOCATE in your example is for an existing dataset.  If you want to create a new output dataset with much longer lines (as Joseph suggested) it needs to be a different dataset, and the ALLOCATE will need changed to point to the new file not the old one.

Also it's possible that despite asking for a file with RECFM(V) or VB etc that's not what the system actually created.  You need to make sure that the output file really does have a long LRECL before you try to use it.  Some systems may override what you ask for and create 80 byte record files (using what's known as SMS rules).